# How can I control a Python script with key inputs?

Tags: python, input, keyboard, raspberry-pi, robotics

I have created a Python script that can take commands from a pipe (named pipe1). I tested the script (I wrote manually in the pipe in the terminal) and it worked.

Now I want to control the script with another Python script, that could write in the pipe if I press `w`, `a`, `s`, or `d`.

You can find the Script on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/2r1Eedhe)

**I started with this script:**

In this example I just want to print the keys that I press. I would later add the `echo ""` commands to write in the pipe, which I tested before.

```
import time
import sys

def key_inp (event):
print 'Key:', event.char
key_press = event.char
sleep_time = 0.030

while True:
        try:
        if key_press.lower() == 'w':
        print "w"
        elif key_press.lower() == 's':
        print "s"
        elif key_press.lower() == 'a':
        print "a"
        elif key_press.lower() == 'd':
        print "d"
        elif key_press.lower() == 'q':
        print "q"
        elif key_press.lower() == 'e':
        print "e"
        elif key_press.lower() == 'p':
        print "stop"

        except(KeyboardInterrupt):
        print('Finished')
```

But I always get the the same error:

```
File "key.py", line 12  
    if key_press.lower() == 'w':  
     ^  
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

My problem is that I nowhere found someone with the same problem like me.
I'm open for alternatives for this example script.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your problem is about the indent, which is *very important* in Python:

   ```
   def key_inp(event):
       print 'Key:', event.char
       key_press = event.char
       sleep_time = 0.030

       while True:
           try:
               if key_press.lower() == 'w':
                   print "w"
               elif key_press.lower() == 's':
                   print "s"
               elif key_press.lower() == 'a':
                   print "a"
               elif key_press.lower() == 'd':
                   print "d"
               elif key_press.lower() == 'q':
                   print "q"
               elif key_press.lower() == 'e':
                   print "e"
               elif key_press.lower() == 'p':
                   print "stop"

           except(KeyboardInterrupt):
               print('Finished')
   ```
2. You can also try the following code, it does the same thing in this case, but more simple:

   ```
   def key_inp(event):
       print 'Key:', event.char
       key_press = event.char
       sleep_time = 0.030

       while True:
           try:
               if key_press.lower() == 'p':
                   print "stop"
                   # Do you also want exit here?
                   # If right, then add a `break` here. 
               else:
                   print key_press.lower()

           except(KeyboardInterrupt):
               print('Finished')
   ```
3. Or if you only want print `w`, `s`, `a`, `d`, `q`, `e` if the input is such, and don't print anything if the input isn't in that list (nor it's `p`). Then I'd suggest use a list as follow:

   ```
   def key_inp(event):
       print 'Key:', event.char
       key_press = event.char
       sleep_time = 0.030

       while True:
           try:
               if key_press.lower() in ['w', 's', 'a', 'd', 'q', 'e']:
                   print key_press.lower()
               elif key_press.lower() == 'p':
                   print "stop"

           except(KeyboardInterrupt):
               print('Finished')
   ```

---

About the indent in Python, I found [this mail](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2007-January/051903.html) which says:

> Python uses indentation to define blocks. For example, to show which 
>   statements are controlled by a `for` or `if` statement, the controlled 
>   statements are indented. Your book should talk about this.
>
> So when typing these examples you need to indent the lines after the 
>   `for`, `if` or `while`. The indentation can be any consistent whitespace. 
>   Four spaces is a very common indent.

Comment: I upvoted because you have answered the question an suggested an improvement, but perhaps you could edit this to be less condescending/abrasive. For example, there is not need for repeating the word "very" in all caps and bold three times. Same with the three question marks before suggesting an improvement. It comes across like you think the poster is stupid, but clearly this is just a case of someone who is a novice to programming/python.

Comment: @Kiven Guan: Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin Guan Thanks for the fast answer. My problem now is, that whenever i execute the script (with your edits) it ends immediately. I wanted it to continue until i press Ctrl+c. What i have to change if i want it to continue permanently?

Comment: @nudelkopf: Did you run the function?

Comment: @KevinGuan I created a new script with readchar: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Abie6SSq). Now it works with my other script.

Comment: @nudelkopf: That's what I meant: In your question, you put the code in a **function**. But in this script, you didn't put the code in a function. That's why it ends immediately. You should call `key_inp()` function after you defined it.